# Conditional Probability of Train Arriving on Time

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that a train is scheduled to arrive at its destination at noon. Also suppose that

if it experiences no major problems it will arrive before noon with probability $0.9$,

if it experiences one major problem it will arrive before noon with probability $0.5$,

if it experiences two major problems it will arrive before noon with probability $0.1$, and

if it experiences more than two major problems it will not arrive before noon.

If the probability of no major problems is $0.5$, the probability of one major problem is $0.2$, the probability of two major problems is $0.2$, and the probability of more than two major problems is $0.1$, given that the train will arrive before noon, what is the probability of no major delays?

**Attempted Solution:**

P(no major problems | arrives before noon) =

P(no major problems $\cap$ arrives before noon)/P(arrives before noon)

$${.5(.9)\over .5(.9)+.2(.5)+.2(.1)+.1(0)} = .7895$$

Did I do this correctly?

Comment: Yes. And the train is likely an Indian one.